# Formdata not being sent to database from browsers on mobile phone though it's working on desktop (frontend deployed on netlify and backend on heroku)

Tags: node.js, axios, frontend, backend

I deployed my frontend application on netlify and backend on heroku. When I'm using the desktop PC, the formdata is being sent to the database, all the functionality works fine. But, when I am trying to do the same from Chrome browser or other browsers on my mobile phone, the data is not being sent.

The following is the code on frontend:

```
  await axios.post(
  "https://tea-website-backend.herokuapp.com/api/v1/contact-form",
  {
    name,
    email,
    msg,
  }
);
```

The backend respective code in app.js:

```
app.use("/api/v1/contact-form", submitFormRouter);
```

The controller functionality is:

```
const Contact = require("../models/Contact");
const { StatusCodes } = require("http-status-codes");


const submitForm = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, message } = req.body;
  const contactForm = await Contact.create({ ...req.body });
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json("Successful");
};

module.exports = {
  submitForm,
};
```

I tried with fetch too but the data is not being sent from mobile browsers (chrome and others, iphone one) though the functionality works from all desktop browsers:

```
await fetch(
      "https://tea-website-backend.herokuapp.com/api/v1/contact-form",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name,
          email,
          msg,
        }),
      }
    )
```

Would appreciate some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I finally troubleshooted the silly bug! My Schema model wasn't accepting the formdata as the values I was trying to send were not satisfying the built-in validators. As I was testing the functionality, I didn't set up any validation on the frontend then- so couldn't figure out what exactly was going wrong. Anyways, it was about a day into sorting out this bug!